# JTextArea Doesn't Show Up on JPanel inside JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I have a JTextArea that sits inside a JScrollPane which in turn sits inside a JPanel and that in turn sits inside a Tab of a JTabbedPane.

I know that text gets added to my JTextArea, but when I move between the tabs, the JTextArea is not visible. To read the text, I have to select the text inside the JTextArea, and that then brings up the White colour of the background of the JTextArea. If I don't select, I don't see anything.

I've tried the usual `revalidate();` and `repaint()` but they're not working for me. Here is some of the code in question:

```
public void writeLogEntry(Alarm alarm)
{


    String value = "Blah Blah Blah";
    logTextArea.append(value);
    SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(contentPane).revalidate();
    repaint();
    revalidate();
    setVisible(true);
}
```

And here is the code for the elements related to the JTextArea:

```
JPanel logPnl = new JPanel();
logPnl.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10, 10));
JScrollPane logScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
logScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
logTextArea = new JTextArea("blah blah");
logTextArea.setBounds(10, 10, 550, 300);
logTextArea.setEditable(false);
logScrollPane.add(logTextArea);
logPnl.add(logScrollPane);

contentTabs.addTab("Alarms Log", null, logPnl, "View Log");
contentPane.add(contentTabs);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please post a complete, succinct fully working code example that produces the problem you've described.

Comment: I thought that was succinct. I can paste the whole JTabbedPane code, but what's inside the other tabs isn't really an issue, and would cause clutter on here. All code related to the JTextArea is posted as far as I know. :(

Comment: We didn't ask for the whole tabbed pane code. We asked for a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Also, don't use setBounds(). Use a proper layout manager.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not be adding components directly to a scrollpane. Instead you add components to the viewport. Or, you specify the component when you create the scrollpane and the component will get added to the viewport for you:

```
//JScrollPane logScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
logScrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
//logTextArea = new JTextArea("blah blah");
logTextArea = new JTextArea(5, 40);
logTextArea.setText("some text");
//logTextArea.setBounds(10, 10, 550, 300);
logTextArea.setEditable(false);
JScrollPane logScrollPane = new JScrollPane(logTextArea);
```

Comment: AWESOME, that did it. Thank you :) Can't believe it was that simple.